# create temp file in android

Tags: android

In my android application i am trying to create a music file using  create temp and trying to read that.Now i am able to create but its giving an error saying video cannot be played.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);  
   //File newfile=new File("/data/data/com.ayansys.samplevideo/Music.3gp");

    //String xyz=newfile.getAbsolutePath();
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); // Sets the window in full screen
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
   // path.g
   // Log.i("Raw folder path:", R.raw.music);
   String path= musicFile();
    try{
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("exception raised",e.toString());
    }
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    // mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.ayansys.samplevideo/"+R.raw.music));

   // File infile=new File("/data/data/com.ayansys.samplevideo/Video.3gp");
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);

    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();

}

public   String  musicFile()
{
    String temPath = null;
    try{
        File outFile=File.createTempFile("music", ".3gp", getDir(temPath, MODE_PRIVATE));
        temPath=outFile.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream f=new FileOutputStream(outFile);
        //FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("music.3gp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        URL u = new URL("http://59.162.166.211/aptv-web/VODAFONE/STARONE/SarabhaivsSarabhai/J2ME/SarabhaivsSarabhai_05.3gp");
    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setDoOutput(true);
    c.connect();
    //FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/videooutput.mp4"));


    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int len1 = 0;
    while ( (len1 = in.read(buffer))!= -1 ) {
         f.write(buffer,0,len1);
    }

    f.close();
    String str=outFile.getAbsolutePath();
    //outFile..close();
    in.close();

}
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception raised in creating a file: "+e.toString());
    }
    return temPath;
}
```

}

I would like to play this.
Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This problem have solved before. [stackoverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6485850/967548

Answer (score 3):

`Context.openFileOutput(String name, int mode)` opens a file on the internal storage.

I suggest you read the [Android Data Storage Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) as it covers both internal and external storage concerns.