# Android How to use and create temporary folder

Tags: android, android-emulator, directory

I develop an app which collects some data from internet. Then save it to a temporary folder. To build this app I need to create and access a folder ( just for the purpose of app, not for the user). How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this code is to create folder:

```
File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/New Folder");

   if(!direct.exists())
    {
        (direct.mkdir()) //directory is created;

    }
```

try it may help you

Answer (score 1):

```
File mFile;
```

**onCreate()**

```
mFile= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/temp/";
```

mFile.mkdir();

**onDestroy();**

```
mFile.delete();
```

Comment: there's no guaranty onDestroy is going to get called. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()

Answer (score 1):

try out this...

```
private void makeFolder(){

File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + File.separator + getString(R.string.folder_name));
    boolean mainfolderexist = root.exists();
        if (!mainfolderexist) {
            try {
                if (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().canWrite()) {
                    root.mkdirs();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

All The best

Answer (score 0):

You should really check this other SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485850/65716

Aside from the fact that you have to completely manage your use of the space, etc, caching on external storage requires more permission for your app.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()

"Apps require no extra permissions to read or write to the returned path, since this path lives in their private storage."

Comment: That was creating temp file. Not quite the same as what is being ask here though...

Comment: @YuchenZhong on the contrary, because the question stated "Then save it to a temporary folder" and "just for the purpose of app, not for the user" would drive you to a cache file.  The accepted answer is fraught with many pitfalls and potential space-hogging bugs.

Answer (score 0):

For app use only, I would recommend to use `Context.getDir()` for retrieving the directory if the files is used by our app only and don`t want to be visible to users by file browsers.

```java
// No need to check if exist, created automatically.
File tempRoot = context.getDir("temp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 

// do something
```

Comment: and how about creating file under that temp. is it allowable? or denieable ? @LarryHsiao

Comment: Yes is allowable, no permission required. It will be created at the apps internal file path. like `/data/user/0/package_name/app_temp/`.
To create a file, `new File(tempRoot, "fileName").createNewFile();`

Comment: i should try one ... ok @Larry