# camera photo image full size imageview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a View with a button and an imageview. There I want to take a large size photo with the android camera and set it in the imageview. With the following Code I get no Image in the imageview. What is wrong in my code?Please help.Thank you for help

```
package de.camera.test;
...

public class CameratestActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public File mTemp;
public ImageView image;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent camera = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    try {
        mTemp = File.createTempFile("myCameraShot", null);
        camera.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                Uri.fromFile(mTemp));
        startActivityForResult(camera, 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data == null)
        return;
    Bitmap b;
    try {
        b = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(mTemp));

        image.setImageBitmap(b);
        Drawable d = image.getDrawable();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Layout main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/preview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `File.createTempFile("myCameraShot", null)` says that a temporary file is created in the default location for temporary files. There is a good chance that this file is protected such that only your app has access to it.

I think something you can try is specify a filepath which is on the SD card.

I also suggest you look at this: [Creating temporary files in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425906/creating-temporary-files-in-android)