# Android reuse stream in BitmapFactory.decodeStream()

Tags: android, memory-management, bitmap, stream

We need to downsample image received from InputStream. It is an image received from some URL and it can be either pretty small or very large. To fit this image in memory we have to downsample it. First we retrieve image size with the help of `inJustDecodeBounds` and calculate necessary sample. Then we create downsampled bitmap by specifying this sample in `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize`. This 2-steps decoding needs two calls of `decodeStream()` and works just fine.

This works just fine for files from SD card. But in our case input stream cannot be reset so we can't call `decodeStream()` twice. Cloning of input stream is also not an option because of its huge size. Alternatively, we can create 2 HTTP requests to the same URL: first to get image size, and then to decode actual image with downsampling, but this solution seems to be rather ugly.

Can we reuse stream which cannot be reset? Or please propose some known workarounds for this problem.

Comment: You could download the image directly to the sd-card and decode it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan't to reuse the stream it is obviously must be saved to either RAM or the SD-card, because network InputStream (let's imagine it is not Buffered) is not keeping downloaded data.

So the option to workaround this as said before is to save image directly to the sd-card (maybe in some [temp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425906/creating-temporary-files-in-android) directory) if image could really huge.