# Deleting an image after shared transition

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, transition

I am creating an app with a shared transition animation. For this I create an intent with an image. But the image gets stored on the device. But how can I delete this aftere the transition?

Here I share the transition:

```
Bitmap photo = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), photo, "pic", null);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

And here I recieve the uri:

```
pic = extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

And here I try to delete the image, but it doesn't find it:

```
File fdlt = new File(pic.getPath());
        if (fdlt.exists()) {
            if (fdlt.delete()) {
                Log.e("DELETED", "DELETED");
            } else {
                Log.e("NOT DELETED", "NOT DELETED");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("FILE NOT FOUND", "FILE NOT FOUND");
        }
```

Example path of an image: `/external/images/media/2750`

Comment: can you show us the value of `path`?

Comment: Yeah, sure @Sohail Zahid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File fdlt = new File(pic.getPath());
        if (fdlt.exists()) {
            if (fdlt.delete()) {
                Log.e("DELETED", "DELETED");
            } else {
                Log.e("NOT DELETED", "NOT DELETED");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("FILE NOT FOUND", "FILE NOT FOUND");
        }
```

Replace your this code with below one.

```
        int size = 0;
        size = this.getContentResolver().delete(pic,
                null, null);
        if (size == 0) {
            Log.e("NOT DELETED", "NOT DELETED");
        } else {
            Log.e("DELETED", "DELETED");
        }
```

Comment: comment here if still have issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the image in your app's cache dir, and let Android take care of deleting it: [Creating temporary files in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425906/creating-temporary-files-in-android)